# Input type="time" broken since last update of Chrome (does not get selected on click)

Tags: html, angular, input, timepicker

We are using Angular 7 and input fields of type="time" in the following way:

```
        <input
          type="time"
          (change)="updateBeginValidator()"
          formControlName="beginTime">
```

This used to work fine.

Since the last update of Chrome, the time does not get selected, when clicking on it. This looks weird, as there is also no cursor displayed - it looks like there is no input possible.
It only gets selected after any key is pressed.

Comment: I use Chrome 90.0.4430.85 and it seems to work fine. What's the version you have?

Comment: The same one': Version 90.0.4430.85 (Offizieller Build)

Comment: By the way - it was a few days later working again. Chrome changed it obviously back.